# Failed to fetch rows returns IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception

Tags: c#, db2

My query is working fine when I am using query browser and the fetch time is around 20-30 secs with 1000 rows.

However If I am going to bind my query on my code it throws me an exception without providing specific error details even I already removed the try-catch block on the line. Here the sample details and snapshot of the error:

IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception: 'External component has thrown an exception.'
[image]

Here is my sample code:

```
myConnection.Open();

string query = "SELECT colA, colB FROM TableA";

DB2Command selectCommand = new DB2Command(query, myConnection);
List<x> l = new List<x>();


DB2DataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    x res = new x();

    res.myVarA = reader.GetString(0).Trim();
    res.myVarB = reader.GetString(1).Trim();    

    l.Add(res);
}
myConnection.Close();
return l;
```

Here is the full error details on exception:

```
+       $exception  {IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [57014] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2DataReader.Read()
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()}  IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace? It might show what that external component is.

Comment: I updated the question now you can see the full details of exception

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql0952n-error-returned-long-running-sql-statement ... Can you try increasing `selectCommand.CommandTimeout`? You said it runs 20-30 seconds. Maybe try 60 for starters?

Comment: you mean the Connection Lifetime on the connection string?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the `CommandTimeout` property on the command object.

Comment: ...so do `selectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60;` just before calling `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: great it works!. appreciate your help tnx!

Comment: No problem. Just keep an eye on that query performance.